# Selecting the maximum value only for another maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have two int data type columns in SQL Server, how can I write a query so that I get the maximum number, at the maximum number of the other column?

Let me give an example. Lets say I have this table:

```
|  Name | Version | Category | Value | Number | Replication |
|:-----:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|:-----------:|
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   123 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   456 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   312 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   645 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   369 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   258 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   741 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   734 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   997 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   997 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   438 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   735 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   786 |      2 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   486 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   379 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   943 |      2 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Time     |   123 |      3 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Size     |   456 |      3 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Time     |   312 |      3 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Size     |   645 |      3 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Time     |   369 |      3 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Size     |   258 |      3 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Time     |   741 |      3 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Size     |   734 |      3 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.3     | Time     |   997 |      4 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.3     | Size     |   997 |      4 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.3     | Time     |   438 |      4 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.3     | Size     |   735 |      4 |           1 |
```

How could I write a query so that I selected the maximum `Replication` value at the maximum `Number` value? As you can see, in this table, the maximum value in Number is `4` but the maximum number in `Replication` where `Number = 4` is `1`

All I can think to do is this:

```
SELECT MAX(Replication) FROM Table
WHERE Number IS MAX;
```

which is obviously wrong and doesn't work.

Comment: could you please post here your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Group By` and `Having`

```
select max(Replication) from Table_Name group by [Number] having 
[Number]=(select max([Number]) from Table_Name)
```

Comment: That was it! I'm still very klutzy when it comes to group by and having.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery to find the max number in the where clause. If you just want one single number as the result there is no need to use group by and having (which would make the query a lot more expensive):

```
select max([replication]) from tab
where number = (select max(number) from tab)
```